# Magento 2, $productRepository->get($sku) doesn't include product ID?

Tags: magento2, product

I'm using the following to load a product by SKU:

```
/* $this->productRepository (populated by DI) \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository */
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
```

However, when calling `$product->getData()` or `$product->getId()`, there is no ID returned. I have looked at the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::get()` method and it does find the ID correctly. Other data is included as expected:

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [website_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [attribute_set_id] => 9
    [type_id] => simple
    [tax_class_id] => 1
    [visibility] => 1
    [created_at] => 1459845988
    [sku] => ABC
    [name] => Some product
    [status] => 1
    [price] => 1.00
    [meta_title] => Some product
    [meta_keyword] => 
    [meta_description] => 
    [description] => Product description here
    [short_description] => Short product description here
    [size] => 4
    [stock_data] => Array
        (
            [use_config_manage_stock] => 0
            [manage_stock] => 1
            [min_sale_qty] => 1
            [max_sale_qty] => 2
            [is_in_stock] => 1
            [qty] => 1000
        )

    [related_products] => Array
        (
        )

    [cross_sell_products] => Array
        (
        )

    [up_sell_products] => Array
        (
        )

    [tier_price] => Array
        (
        )

    [tier_price_changed] => 0
)
```

Why does the returned Product object not include this key data?

Comment: What Magento version do you use? I've just checked it on 2.1.0 with demo data and it worked properly for me.